# Saving the canvas together with the Div

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am creating a program where the user will upload an image and the program will display a div above the canvas and solved this problem already. But  my problem is when I am trying to save/download the image, it will only save the canvas.

```
<div id="memePlaceHolder" style="height: 700px; width:700px;background:#BBB;">
    <canvas id="c" width="0" height="0">
    </canvas>        
    <div id="myTestDiv" name="myTestDiv">
       <h1>#Test Hashtag</h1>
       <br/>
       <h2>My Test Display</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used this code to save/download the canvas.

```
e.downloadLink.href = e.c.toDataURL();
```

Is there a method to save the image together with the div displayed above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using a JavaScript library called [**html2canvas**](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com).

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
let title = document.querySelector('#title');
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 150, 150);
}
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg';

function save() {
    html2canvas(wrapper, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            a.download = 'myImage.png';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#title {font: 16px Verdana;color: #07C}#canvas {border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="title">DreiDreiDrei</div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
<button onclick="save()">Save as Image</button>
```

To learn more about the library, refer to the official [documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. BTW will this affect the quality of the image?

Comment: um.. I guess no. it usually saves the image with highest quality

Comment: I have a concern, do you have any idea how to fix the problem where the font on the image changes when I tried to download the generated Image?

Comment: um.. its currently unclear what you're asking. it would be better if you ask a new question with additional details, to get a proper solution to the problem.

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks. I'll try asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't save the div with the canvas element,